# Can anyone please help me in understanding this assembly language code?

Tags: c, assembly

C code:

```
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
          x[i] = x[i] + 2;
         }

     a = a + 3;
```

Assembly language code:

```
              L.D F0,0(R1)
              STALL
              ADD.D F4,F0,#2
              STALL
              STALL
              S.D F4,F0(R1)
              DADDUI R1,R1,#-8
              STALL
              L.D R2,#0
              BNE R1,R2,Loop
              L.D F5,#0
              ADD.D F5,F5,#3
```

Actually I am not able to understand the assembly code as well as why have we put stalls in between instructions. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Which CPU architecture? There are many assembly languages.

Comment: (a) Some of the assembly code is missing. (b) You did not state which processor this is for.

Comment: It's not assembly code, it's a mixture of pseudo-MIPS64 and explicit pipeline annotations.

Comment: If your compiler fully unrolled and software-pipelined that 3-iteration loop, it would cost maybe 1.5x the code size but have no stalls even on an in-order pipeline.

Comment: @EOF: Wait a minute, `L.D R2,#0`?  That's a double-precision FP load of an immediate into an integer register.  Also, `S.D F4,F0(R1)` is using `F0` (FP register) as an *index* part of the addressing mode.  MIPS does have indexed FP load/store instructions, but both address registers are integer regs, only the data reg being FP.  So it's almost MIPS64, but actually super broken.

Comment: @PeterCordes I also don't think MIPS has immediate floating point operands for `ADD.D`.

Comment: @EOF: I think you're right but that's at least plausible as a pseudo-instruction in whatever this syntax is.  I don't think MIPS64 even has an immediate `L.D` in hardware; gcc and clang don't use it: https://godbolt.org/z/8sMYbr.  Although they clearly have some missed optimizations where creating an integer bit-pattern for `dmtc1` would be better than setting up to address a static constant.  (They use `dmtc1 $f0, $0` for 0.0, so presumably creating a `-0.0` bit pattern with a couple integer instructions would be cheaper.  Or one `lui` to create `1.0f`)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asm doesn't make sense (or is full of typos) and thus can't really be explained.

Answer (score 1):

```
                  // Loop set-up is missing.
                  // Loop label is missing.
L.D F0,0(R1)      // Load x[i] into F0.
STALL             // Wait for load to finish.
ADD.D F4,F0,#2    // Add two to F0 and put result into F4.
STALL             // Wait for add to finish.
STALL             // Wait for add to finish.
S.D F4,F0(R1)     // Store F4 into x[i].
DADDUI R1,R1,#-8  // Decrease index to next x[i].
STALL             // Wait for add to finish.
L.D R2,#0         // Load zero into R2.
BNE R1,R2,Loop    // Repeat loop if index is not yet zero.
L.D F5,#0         // Load zero into F5. Hypothesis: This initializes a to zero, per C code not shown in question.
ADD.D F5,F5,#3    // Add three to a.
                  // Store of a is missing.
```

Comment: This asm doesn't actually match the C, and some of it makes no sense at all. `S.D F4,F0(R1)` uses F0 (an FP register) as an index, part of the address, for a store!!   `L.D R2,#0` is an FP load-immediate into an *integer* register, which is used in the next instruction for `BNE`.  (I see you turned the OP's `#0` into `#0.`)  If this was actual MIPS like `DADDUI` and `L.D` hints at, a sane implementation would use `BNE` against `R0`, the architectural zero register.

Comment: Those differences from the C might just be typos, e.g. `F0(R1)` might be a typo for `0(R1)` to use the same addressing mode as the load.  But then it would be looping `do{ *ptr += 2.0; }while(--ptr != NULL);` unless `x[]` is a static array that happens to start at absolute address `8`.  (Possible in the data section on MARS or something, depending on your memory map).

Comment: @PeterCordes: I agree the register types are off. I did not intend to change `0` to `0.` (and that is an odd typo; I am not sure where it came from, except that the `.` key is next to the `/` key I was typing. The loop iteration direction matches the C if you allow the optimizer to reverse the loop order. But it is a puzzle how the OP got this mismatched code to be comprehended.

Comment: Yeah, loop direction is not a showstopper, but the loop *bound* certainly is.  (Unless like I suggested, `x[]` happens to be at address `8`.)  R1 is a true pointer, not an index or byte offset, in `0(R1)`.

Comment: Also, I don't see a reason for a stall after `daddui r1, r1, #-8`.  The `l.d` into R2 is independent.  A stall before `bne` is plausible in a hypothetical MIPS without bypass forwarding, but it should be after `l.d`.  It would be super weird for a pipeline to have bypass forwarding for FP but not integer, and we see `L.D F5,#0` forward to an `add.d`.  Also we see "integer" bypass forwarding from `L.D R2,#0` to `bne` without a stall. I can't think of a plausible reason for that stall in a sane pipeline (i.e. without insane resource conflicts). The other stalls which all make sense (RAW hazards)